# Not able to upload all types of files on IoT Hub via C code

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to upload files to azure Iot Hub by following c code using C-SDK library . But in Azure Iot hub , only text files , jpg files etc are being uploaded and files like png ,xlsx,pdf etc are not being uploaded correctly . What is the issue? . What is the correct method to upload all kinds of files to Iot-Hub via C code ?

Please refer to the following upload files link:-
And I'm working on this code for uploading all kinds of files to IoT Hub.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob/iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob.c

```
//function to read a file in a character buffer

unsigned char* readfileintobuffer()
{

    FILE *fp;
    size_t numOfBytesRead;
    unsigned char* buffer;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\t-pra\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\j.png","r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long lSize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char*) * lSize);
    numOfBytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char*), lSize, fp);
    return buffer;
}
```

```
IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_UploadToBlob(device_ll_handle, "subdir/w3.png", 
readfileintobuffer ,lSize) != IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK
```

Expected :- all kinds of files getting uploaded on Iothub.

Actual :- png , xlsx , pdf etc files not being able upload on Iothub .

Also help with the exact method in C to upload all kind of files to IoTHub .

Answer (score 1):

The Azure IoT C SDK does not evaluate the extensions of the files being uploaded. 
The file path provided through the API functions are passed as-is to Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: But jpg files and text files are getting stored correctly in the container . According to this extensions are getting converted . What might be the issue .